# How to dynamically change the chart series # in google charts comboChart

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, graph, charts

I have a page which displays a tickbox for each series in the chart.

- [ ] Series 0 label
- [ ] Series 1 label
- [ ] Series 2 label

When clicking a checkbox, I want to dynamically set the series number to display the correct series as a line over the barchart.  So where the series is 0 in the code below, I want to dynamically change this based on the selected option on the form.

How can this be done?  Thank you.

```
return {
    ...this.chartOptions,
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {
        0: {
            type: "line", 
            curveType: "function"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doh!  Finally got it, I had to put the variable containing the series between []

```
return {
...this.chartOptions,
seriesType: 'bars',
series: {
    [variable]: {
        type: "line", 
        curveType: "function"
    }
}
```

}